# Error extraño con las contraseñas

Tags: laravel-5

Quiero dar a mis usuarios (la tabla User) la opción de que modifiquen la contraseña.

Para ello, tengo este sencillo formulario:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Cambie su contraseña para cersionarse de que no suplanten su identidad</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('clave.cambiar',$u)}}" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Contraseña</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Confirmar Contraseña</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Actualizar Contraseña
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Sin embargo, pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando cargo la vista, veo que aparece en la caja de la contraseña un texto.
Si hago visible el texto no aparece y si le doy un valor predeterminado al texto sustituye a ese valor *(pero no en caso de que `value=""`)*.

¿Que hago para que no aparezca ningún texto?

Edito: En algunos ordenadores este problema se soluciona y limpio completamente el historial, pero en otros ordenadores el problema persiste.

Comment: no será el autocompletar del navegador?

Comment: intenta en el formulario donde estan los campos de clave ponerle autocomplete en off es decir <form autocomplete="off"

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas He intentado "<form method="POST" action="cambiar_clave" autocomplete="off" novalidate>", pero no ha funcionado.

Comment: Por cierto, ahora he cargado la página y ya no aparece el texto. Probablemente se debera a que he borrado mi historial.

Comment: cambia el nombre de la variable. el post queda con valores si no lo limpias

Comment: @JackNavaRow Es decir, en vez de llamarlos password y password-confirm, pongo otros nombres, como por ejemplo clave y clave-config.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Así he probado y parece que la vista funciona bien. Aún tengo que probar en más ordenadores, pero si va bien habre solucionado mi problema y podre darte los puntos de recompensa. ¿Cómo se haria eso?

Comment: agrega tu la respuesta como lo solucionastes. el error es que tienes una clave almacenada en el chrome y cuando lee el campo password te lo autocompleta

Comment: Intenta en modo incógnito de tu navegador

Comment: Pues al final tampoco sirve cambiar el nombre de las variables. Voy a tener que probar un buen formatero de firefox.

Comment: De hecho, en el PC que fallaba he realizado otra prueba, pero esta vez con Chrome, y en el no me ocurre.

Comment: He probado un formateo total de firefox, pero nanai. A ver que es lo que pasa con Firefox Y este PC...

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente sea la función de autocompletado de tu navegador.

Intenta agregando al elemento **input** de la contraseña el atributo autocomplete:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

En caso de que no funcione, puedes intentar con:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora lo que he observado es que podria ser un error de la cache del proyecto.
Al eliminar el historial de Firefox en algunos PC elimina el problema, pero no es así en todos los ordenadores.
Ademas, solo afecta a navegadores Firefox. No ocurre en otros como por ejemplo Chrome.